# Adding vertical lines on line graph distorting scale

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a line graph with datetime in the X axis that I modify the format to show HH:MM:SS

```
fig.update_xaxes(title_font=dict(size=12), tickformat='%X')
```

Before vertical lines are added, the scale is perfect:
[image]

Example 1: vline adding the value: `1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000000`:

[image]

Example 2 vline adding the value: `1970-01-01T00:01:34.000000000`

[image]

**My vertical line code is:**

```
for loop...
if time in df['ColA'].values:
fig.add_vline(x=df[df['ColA'] == time)]['ColB'].values[0])
```

**ColA and variable time (iterator in the loop) is of type string and has values as such. Values are coming from selected rows indices from a callback**

```
0:00:00
0:01:34
```

**ColB is a datetime64[ns] type:**

```
1970-01-01 00:00:00
1970-01-01 00:01:34
```

**And my graph is a px.line graph with facetted rows and im using ColB on the X axis.**

**Why is the scale completely changing if the vline value x is of the same type and within the same range?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- it all comes down to type coercing
- `df["ColA"].values` returns an array of *datetime64[ns]*
- inspect `fig.data[0].x` and it returns an array of *datetime.datetime*
- make them consistent with `pd.Timestamp(time).to_pydatetime()`
- have simulated some data, no faceting as you have not included any details of this in your question

```
ROWS = 20
df = pd.DataFrame({"ColA":pd.date_range("1-jan-1970", freq="4H", periods=ROWS), "ColB":np.random.uniform(1,30, ROWS)})

fig = px.line(df, x="ColA", y="ColB")
fig.update_xaxes(title_font=dict(size=12), tickformat='%X')

for time in df["ColA"].values:
    if time in df['ColA'].values:
        fig.add_vline(x=pd.Timestamp(time).to_pydatetime())

fig
```

[image]

Comment: I noticed that too over the weekend but your answer is so clear thank you. can you please check my related issue after I fixed this  one, hoping you might have an answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69501854/adding-annotation-text-yields-integer-error-message?noredirect=1#comment122847445_69501854

Comment: I've looked at that too and answered