# Adding annotation text yields integer error message

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

When I adding a vline to my graph it works perfect:

```
fig.add_vline(
        x=pd.to_datetime('1970-01-01 00:00:00'),
        line_dash='dot',
        row=0)
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

When I try adding an annotation text alongside the vline I get an error message

```
fig.add_vline(
    x=pd.to_datetime('1970-01-01 00:00:00'),
    line_dash='dot',
    annotation_text='15',
    row=0)
```

> TypeError: Addition/subtraction of integers and integer-arrays with
> Timestamp is no longer supported.  Instead of adding/subtracting `n`,
> use `n * obj.freq`

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the way you're trying to add that annotation. Is that the only line you changed when you received that error?

Comment: @coralvanda Yes I think the issue has been reported as bug https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/3065.  do you know any other workaround

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- as a workaround, do one call to `add_vline()` and one call to `add_annotation()`
- have set parameters to `add_annotation()` such that annotation will be at top of line

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

ROWS = 20
df = pd.DataFrame({"ColA":pd.date_range("1-jan-1970", freq="4H", periods=ROWS), "ColB":np.random.uniform(1,30, ROWS)})

fig = px.line(df, x="ColA", y="ColB")
fig.update_xaxes(title_font=dict(size=12), tickformat='%X')

for time in df["ColA"].values:
    time = pd.Timestamp(time).to_pydatetime()
    fig.add_vline(x=time)
    fig.add_annotation(x=time, y=1, yref="paper", text="15")

fig
```

[image]

#### sub-plots

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

ROWS = 20
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ColA": pd.date_range("1-jan-1970", freq="4H", periods=ROWS),
        "ColB": np.random.uniform(1, 30, ROWS),
        "Facet": np.repeat(["plot 1", "plot 2"], ROWS // 2),
    }
)

fig = px.line(df, x="ColA", y="ColB", facet_row="Facet")
fig.update_xaxes(title_font=dict(size=12), tickformat="%X")

for time, y, facet in df[["ColA", "ColB", "Facet"]].values:
    time = pd.Timestamp(time).to_pydatetime()
    fig.add_vline(x=time, row=0 if facet == "plot 1" else 1)
    fig.add_annotation(x=time, y=y, text="15", row=0 if facet == "plot 1" else 1, col=0)

fig
```

[image]

Comment: how do I incorporate the facet associated to each annotation, you may see the "row" in my px.line code

Comment: the reason SO best practice question is re-producable is for this reason.  you see my answer is re-producable.   updated